# Modify Shipping in Woocommerce cart

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have three countries where I will deliver the goods. I want the client to select the country first and see the delivery methods without updating the entire page, and without using the Update Totals button. Just choose the country and drop shipping options.

This code is i tried but its not working for me.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'wf_modify_rates', 10, 3); 
function wf_modify_rates($available_shipping_methods, $package){ 
    $methords_us = array('flaterate:1','flaterate:2'); 
    if( $package['destination']['country'] == 'US'){ 
        foreach ($available_shipping_methods as $methord_name => $methord) {
            if(!in_array($methord_name, $methords_us)){
                unset($available_shipping_methods[$methord_name]); 
            } 
        } 
    } return $available_shipping_methods; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but in order to update that section you need to have an ajax, now there are some themes that don't have ajax update on the cart/checkout section so in this case more likely you will need to make a custom ajax and add you code in the respon for what do you need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014634/woocommerce-how-can-i-enable-shipping-method-depending-on-total-price look over this